# Pipe execvp linux command from child to parent process

Tags: c, pipe, fork, execvp, dup2

I try to write a program in C language that takes a simple Linux command in input like "ls /home".
This command is executed in child process with "execvp" and sent to the parent process to be displayed on the screen..

My problem is that the program is running and display nothing and don't give back the prompt. I have to quit with "ctrl + C".

Is the problem in the while loop or my pipe send my command nowhere?

Thanks for your feedback

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        int     fd[2];
        int   pid;

        pipe(fd);
        
        if((pid = fork()) == -1)
        {
                perror("fork");
                exit(1);
        }

        if(pid == 0)
        {
                close(fd[0]);

            dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

            close(fd[1]);

            execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
        }
        else
        {
                close(fd[1]);

            dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fd[0]);
            char result;
            while(read(fd[0], &result, sizeof(result) > 0))
            {
                write(fd[1], &result, sizeof(result));
            }
            wait(NULL);
        }
    close(fd[1]); 
    close(fd[0]);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: The parent process tries to write to `fd[1]` which was closed.  Change that to `STDOUT_FILENO`.

Comment: You should have error handling code after `execvp()`.  You don't need to test the return value of `execvp()`: if it succeeds, it doesn't return; if it returns, it failed.  The calls to `close()` at the end are superfluous and always fail.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, I have another problem now it write endless "^" on the stdou. I will check it on my own and try to fix this one

Answer (score 1):

In the **parent**, the read loop has problems. Compare

```
while(read(fd[0], &result, sizeof(result) > 0))
```

to

```
while(read(fd[0], &result, sizeof(result)) > 0)
```

The former, in your program, is using the result of the comparison `sizeof(result) > 0` as the *size* of the buffer, and looping as long as `read` returns a nonzero value.

*Note that `result` is a `char`, and `sizeof (char)` is **guaranteed** to be `1`.*

`1 > 0` is `1`, which just happens to be the size of your buffer, so this partially works. The loop will continue on error (`-1`) though, and will continue to attempt writing output.

It is also trying to read from `fd[0]`, which was closed after

```
dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
close(fd[0]);
```

This duplication is not needed.

Additionally,

```
write(fd[1], &result, sizeof(result));
```

is attempting to write the output back into the pipe. That said, the parent closed this file descriptor earlier (`close(fd[1]);`).

Note the `close(fd[1]);` outside of the `else` block is redundant (and redundant closes can be a source of bugs in more complex programs).

---

In the **child**, you should handle the event that `execvp` fails, because if the function succeeds, it never returns. Anything expected to run *after* `execvp` is operating in a failure state (in your program, that is the lines after the else block).

---

A cursory example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "too few arguments\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (-1 == pipe(fd)) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (-1 == (pid = fork())) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        /* child */
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[1]);

        argv++;

        execvp(*argv, argv);
        perror("execvp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* parent */
    char result;

    close(fd[1]);

    while (read(fd[0], &result, 1) > 0)
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, &result, 1);

    close(fd[0]);
    wait(NULL);
}
```